# Javascript Code error video click

Tags: javascript

So i get this error right here and I don't really understand what it means.

video_click.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Here is the javascript code I am using

```
var v = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
v.addEventListener(
'play', 
function() { 
    v.play();
}, 
false);

v.onclick = function() {
if (v.paused) {
    v.play();
} else {
    v.pause();
}

return false;
};

var a = document.getElementById('videoPlayer2');
a.addEventListener(
'play', 
function() { 
    a.play();
}, 
false);

a.onclick = function() {
if (a.paused) {
    a.play();
} else {
    a.pause();
}

return false;
};
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns null if it can't find an element with the given ID. Based on the line number in the error message, it looks like `var a = document.getElementById('videoPlayer2');` results in `a` being assigned to null. So, when you try to call `a.addEventListener` on the next line, it's failing, because you can't call `addEventListener` on null.

So, it looks like there's no element with an id of `videoPlayer` in your document.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand what I am doing wrong. How would I fix it?

Comment: Well, it really depends on why it can't find `videoPlayer2`. If you've just mistyped the ID of that element (e.g., it should be `videoplayer2` instead), then fixing the typo will fix the problem. If it's completely expected that in some cases there won't be an element with the ID of `videoPlayer2`, then you could just check to make sure `a` is not null before trying to call `a.addEventListener` and `a.onclick`. So after you assign `a`, you could do `if (a !== null) {`, and then put the rest of the code that works on `a` inside that block.

Comment: Work out perfect. Thanks